# Make UIDatePicker Visible Against Black Background

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I've got an app with a date picker against a black background. Before the picker is clicked, it is almost invisible. Is there a way to make it opaque or easier to see? I've messed with the parameters, but nothing seems to do the trick. Thanks in advance!

[Difficult to see unclicked date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZqIx.jpg)

[Clicked date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHcK0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
myDatePicker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you